# fillText over gradient background does not show

Tags: javascript

When I change from strokeText to fillText the text disappears.  I just have a gradient canvas background and I am trying to put fillText over the gradient.  strokeText works fine but when I change to fillText, the text is gone.

```
'''
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(100, 100, 100, 100, 130, 50);
grd.addColorStop(0, "orange");
grd.addColorStop(1, "yellow");

// Fill with gradient
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
ctx.font="20px Georgia";
ctx.strokeText("hello",10,30);
'''
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Comment: better add code snippet with your html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It “disappears” because you only set `fillStyle` once therefore both `fillRect` and `fillText` are the same gradient color. The text is there but it’s blended into the background. Change the fillStyle again before the text.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(100, 100, 100, 100, 130, 50);
grd.addColorStop(0, "orange");
grd.addColorStop(1, "yellow");

// Fill with gradient
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.font="20px Georgia";
ctx.fillText("hello",10,30);
```

The reason it doesn’t do that with stroke is because stroke doesn’t get it’s orders from `fillStyle` so therefore it uses the default which is black.